# Why does 'seem' behave differently?

Tags: syntax, verbs, chomsky, grammatical-subject

- Mary seems[ *t* to be here]
- Mary tried [PRO to be here]

Why can't Mary be generated in spec VP of 'seems' but can in 'tried'?

Instead it looks like it works more like a passive verb:

- Mary is believed [ *t* to be here]

This is in context of The Minimalist Program by Chomsky.

Comment: _Seem_ (and _appear_, which is close to synonymous) are both 1-place A-Raising verbs. As such, they occur with subject clauses that are ungrammatical without syntactic intervention. If the subject clause is an infinitive, A-Raising is required; if it's tensed, Extraposition is required. I.e, *_For him to be tired seems_ and *_That he is tired seems_ are both bad,  but _He seems to be tired_ and _It seems that he is tired_ are both fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that *try* is a two-place predicate that assigns an Agent theta role to *Mary* and a Theme (or similar) role to its infinitival complement, whereas *seems* is **monadic** (in your example), must assign **just one** theta role, to its complement, and cannot have a second argument in its specifier to which it can assign Agent (or any other) role. [Of course, *seems* may also be two-place, e.g., in *It seems **to me** that Mary is an excellent teacher*, but in that case it must have two **'internal'** arguments, and assign a Theme role to the subordinate clause and an **Experiencer** role to the PP complement *to me*; under no circumstances can it assign an Agent role to the PP *to me*, because Agent is never assigned to an internal argument in complement position; Agent can only be assigned in Spec v/V position, and, of course, never by a non-agentive verb like *seems*].

As a consequence of that difference in argument structure between *try* and *seem*, in a sentence like *Mary tried [PRO to be there]* a PRO is needed in the subordinate clause to discharge the Theme role projected by the predicate *be there* and **some other argument** (*Mary*, in this case) is also needed to discharge the Agent role assigned by *try* in the upper clause to its own Spec V. If you had only one argument, i.e., if you base-generated *Mary* as the specifier of *be (there)* in the subordinate clause, and then raised it into the Spec of the higher verb *try*, the chain formed by *Mary* in Spec *try* and its trace in Spec *be* (or by the two copies of *Mary*, under the 'Copy Theory of Movement') would receive **two** theta roles (Agent and Theme, respectively), the Theta Criterion would be violated, and the derivation would be ungrammatical. (Under later versions of Chomskian grammar, of course, that Theta Criterion violation need no longer be invoked to block the derivation: since *Mary* already has a valued role attribute in Spec *be*, it could never be raised into a higher thematic position, e.g., Spec *try*, because there would be **no feature to check** in Spec *try* and Economy would automatically forbid that movement. *Mary* could still raise, of course, but not in search of a second theta role; it could raise directly into Spec Tense, for example, to check its Nominative Case feature there, but it would have to do so skipping Spec *try*, and therefore would never get assigned a second theta role as Agent of *try* anyway.

On the contrary, in a sentence like *Mary seems [t to be there]* (where, recall, *seems* is monadic and assigns a theta role **only to its complement**, **not** to its specifier), replacing 't' with a PRO in the subordinate clause would make the sentence ungrammatical, because, in that case, it would be PRO that would receive the only undischarged theta role available in the sentence (the Theme role assigned by *be there*). *Mary*, on the contrary, **would not receive any theta role** in Spec *seems*, and, again, the Theta Criterion would be violated (by defect, in this case) and the sentence would be ungrammatical. If *Mary* is base-generated as a Spec of *be there*, though, it gets the Theme role assigned by *be there*, and, as the higher verb *seems* does not assign any theta role to its own specifier, *Mary* never receives a second theta role, the Theta Criterion is not violated, and the sentence is well formed.

Answer (score 0):

*seem* is a **raising** verb, *try* is an **equi/control** verb ('equi verb' and 'contol verb' are usually used synonymously).

Equi verbs have a semantic subject: It is part of the meaning of *to try* that there is someone who is trying, which is Mary in this case. **The verb *try* selects *Mary* as an argument**, more specifically, as the subject argument. This subject starts of as the subject of the embedded clause and is raised up to the subject of the matrix clause, if you believe in a transformational syntax.
The same does not hold for raising verbs: **There isnt's any actual seemer**, someone who fills a thematic role in the seeming event. If anything, a grammatical subject in a sentene with *seem* as the main verb would be realized by *it* (as in *It seems that Mary is here*), but then it is clear that this *it* is just a filler for something that would otherwise be empty, because there is no semantic subject; just like in *It is raining*, when *it* is not an actual subject that is raining; *rain* is a zero-place verb. The *it* in both senetences is merely a phonetic filler that needs to be there because English doesn't want the subject position to be emtpy, but there are cases where this pseudo-subject isn't an actual subject. The verb *seem* doesn't have any more theta role to assign, because there isn't a "seemer" - contrary to the verb *try*, which does assign the theta role of agent (namely the one who is trying). And since *Mary* is not selected as an argument of *seem*, it can not be generated as a subject in SpecVP.
It's simply the semantics of the two verbs that make them behave syntactically different.

Also note the difference between subject-oriented and object-oriented raising and equi verbs. *seem* and *try* are both subject-oriented: The filler element takes the position of the subject in the matrix clause.
The example you gave with *believe* is an object-oriented raising verb. The reason why you chose the passive sentence is that *Mary* is actually the object of the outer sentence: Having started as the subject of the embedded clause (*Mary is here*), it is **raised to the object position** of the matrix clause (*John believes [Mary] to be here*). But ***Mary* is not semantically selected by the verb *believe*** - the verb doesn't assign any theta role that Mary now fills; Mary isn't "the believed" or something it's just there due to the syntactic operation of raisin. With this behavirous, *believe* is an object-oriented raising verb.
An example an object-oriented equi verb is *persuade*, as in *Peter persuaded Mary to be here*: *Mary* starts as the subject of the embedded clause and is raised to the object of the matrix clause. However, it is also **selected by the verb**: Mary is the one who is being persuaded; she fills an argument position that is semantically required by the verb - there is someone who is being persuaded, and this role is satisfied by the now raised *Mary*. This makes *persuade* an object-oriented equi verb.

All these behave synactically differently, but the main distinction is simply whether or not the NP in question fills a theta role that is semantically required by the verb.

Comment: The surface subject of 'try to be there' does NOT 'start off as the subject of the embedded clause and is raised up to the subject of the matrix clause', contrary to your statement at the end of your first paragraph. That never happens to 'equi'/'control' verbs like 'try', for reasons I explained carefully in my own answer. It is RAISING verbs like 'seem' that force the subject of their infinitival complement clause to raise, precisely because that subject would violate the Case Filter in situ and 'seem' etc. have no subject of their own that can raise to Spec T and satisfy the EPP.